# try catch err instanceof not recognizing custom error class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've created a custom exception error class, `BookingError`, that is supposed to handle all booking-related errors that are thrown:

```
class BookingError extends Error{
    constructor(message: string){
        super(message);
        this.name = "BookingError";
    }
}
```

When using this to throw exceptions, I've run into an issue where I *cannot* reliably check the `instanceof` against the class to decide what to do with the error.

```
const throwError = () => {
    throw new BookingError("This is a test.");
};

const testErrorException = () => {
    try{
        throwError();
    } catch(err: unknown){
        // This will always result in a false output.
        console.log(err instanceof BookingError);
    }
};
```

This code will result in the following:

> Error [BookingError]: This is a test.

**EDIT:** Interestingly enough, albeit hacky, the following code will result in the expected output:

```
if((err as BookingError).name === "BookingError"){
    // This will output "This is a test."
    console.log((err as BookingError).message);
}
```

Comment: This gives me `true`. I tried it in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD28DWBLAdgcwKICcfx2gFMAPAFyLQBMZd8cBvAKGlemHjQjJwFdgyBABQBbIlDAYiALmjcc6DAEpmbNXN4AHIjlHiIkokoDcLdazIALFBAB0aMGOgBeaACIEyRXQJvTagF8mIKYOLjJoK3wAdx9CVyElFwA+aFU2KPho6DQibM9UTDihNwAVaxgbaDBI8TJbNxNg01DOblruOKwSYCJNMhROF2hElLSzCxwAT3TzTNi8YSbA9jAyYEshHRwVCfUAen3ocqrolBAQapBosCmYHHFeEAj0augAMzAQCCJoeF4yJoAbY9mowhB4CAiLYQPAMFs8NB0NwwGhevB3nBEIVsIsdv42EEAi0KJ08d1ev1BmhEsYgA)

Comment: Could you please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in which it outputs as `false`, probably in a playground?

Comment: @ShriHariL All relevant information from my codebase is included.

Comment: If so, then shall we print `console.log(err)` to debug the object instance.

Comment: @ShriHariL The result of `console.log(err)` is `Error [BookingError]: This is a test.`

Comment: You might have multiple instances of `BookingError`, are you using a package manager, having incorrect versioning can cause this.  What module loader / bundler are you using?, Or are you using pure ES modules.

Comment: Also try doing a full search of you app, make sure you have just not defined this class in multiple units.  Lastly, are you using it between webworkers / cluster etc, as instance won't be the same between threads..

Comment: @Keith `BookingError` is only declared once in the entire app :)

Comment: `EDIT: Interestingly enough,`  Yes, doing that helps when you have multiple class definitions.  Were or how your getting this is hard to tell.   One idea though is place a `console.log('create BookingError')`  just before the `class BookingError extends...`, see if you get more than 1 console log.

Comment: Multiple instances of a class definition can be a pain to track down, it was common for React apps to fail for this very reason, and the reason React has built-in support to check for this.  Often semantic versioning was incorrectly setup up etc, and you could end up with say version `16.0.0.1` & `16.0.0.2` been installed, and yes, just something as simple as that would cause React to fail.

Comment: If your transpiling to es5 or below this will fail. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD28DWBLAdgcwKICcfx2gFMAPAFyLQBMZd8cBvAKGlemHjQjJwFdgyBABQBbIlDAYiALmjcc6DAEpmbNXN4AHIjlHiIkokoDcLdazIALFBAB0aMGOgBeaACIEyRXQJvTagF8mIKYOLjJoK3wAdx9CVyElFwA+aFU2KPho6DQibM9UTDihNwAVaxgbaDBI8TJbNxNg01DOblruOKwSYCJNMhROF2hElLSzCxwAT3TzTNi8YSbA9jAyYEshHRwVCfUAen3ocqrolBAQapBosCmYHHFeEAj0augAMzAQCCJoeF4yJoAbY9mowhB4CAiLYQPAMFs8NB0NwwGhevB3nBEIVsIsdv42EEAi0KJ08d1ev1BmhEsYgA

Comment: @AluanHaddad  Ah, yes.  To fix you would need to correct the prototype -> `(this as any).__proto__ = BookingError.prototype;`.  But to be fair in this day and age I would say it's pretty safe to set target minimum to `ES2015` ,

Comment: @Keith Indeed that's true, but as per several of your previous comments there are other reasons to avoid relying on `instanceof` in JS.